# Get the values from checkboxes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this for-each loop to display (and set checked if suitable):

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-xl-6">
    @if (Model.PersonTypes != null)
    {
        foreach (var _t in Model.AllPersonTypes)
        {
            <label class="kt-checkbox kt-checkbox--bold kt-checkbox--brand">
                <input type="checkbox" name="PersonType" checked="@Model.PersonTypes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.PersonTypeName == _t.PersonTypeName)"> @_t.PersonTypeName
                <span class="kt-margin-l-10"></span>
            </label>
        }
    }
</div>
```

`Model.PersonTypes` contains the types the `Person` belongs to, `Model.AllPersonTypes` contain all available person types

[image]

What I need is how to get the selected values when updating the `Person` details in the controller

Comment: Wrap the markup in <form></form> and the use Request.Form to get the data in your controller method

Comment: It is already inside a form

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveProfileInfo", "Person", FormMethod.Post))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST model (model accepted by your post action) should contain a property that holds a collection of, let's say int - or whatever your PersonType primary key data type is. Then modify your checkbox element to include a value.

```
public class PostPersonTypeModel {
    public List<int> PersonType {get;set;} = new List<int>();
}
```

```
<input   type="checkbox" 
         name="PersonType" 
         checked="@Model.PersonTypes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.PersonTypeName == _t.PersonTypeName)" 
         value="@_t.PersonTypeID"> @_t.PersonTypeName
```

Your `PostPersonTypeMode.PersonType` collection would then hold one element for each checked item.